# How to copy faster between PC and Server

Tags: networking, ethernet

My home network consists of a WiFi router to which multiple wireless devices connect and to which my PC and server are wired over Gigabit Ethernet. Copy speeds between the PC and server are between 80 MB/s and 120 MB/s. I copy huge video files between them, and for this purpose, that is slow. If I were to get Ethernet cards (they're using the Ethernet port built-in to the motherboard right now) with, say, dual ports, could I gang those together and run wires directly between the PC and server for increased throughput? Or somehow have all 3 ports work together between the two machines? By the way, each of those machines can copy directly from/to their own drive at hundreds of MB/s, so drive speed isn't the limiting factor.

My PC is running Windows 10 and my server is running Windows Server 2016.

NOTE: I've seen something about "trunking" but don't know how it works or how to set it up, or even it's what I want to do.

Comment: Most consumer routers do not support creating a trunk port.  A trunk port wouldn't increase or decrease the transfer speeds between two devices .

Comment: Kindly check if the methods in this similar thread was helpful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/114021/fastest-copy-to-copy-files-over-the-network-between-windows-7-pcs

Answer (score 0):

A Gigabit network is on the order of 100 Mega**byte**. (Faster in raw speed, but subtract packet overhead, etc. - easiest to divide by 10). End result: 120 Megabytes/second is close to the limit.

Double or triple would by nice. I'm not sure if that would truly work as expected or not. It might. But at best, that is double or triple.

Far better would be 10 Gigabit **fiber**. [Something like this StarTech card](https://amzn.to/2LmHWBY):

[image: StarTech 10 Gig. fiber]

Other brands may be more or less expensive. This StarTech was the first one I found, but while I have used plenty of other StarTech products, I have not used this particular card so I can't say how good it is - just an example of the genre.

You also need to add SFP transceivers, cable, and possibly a switch.

Add it all up and it is not a cheap fix, but it should give you much higher throughput than any bundling of 1 Gig. links.

Comment: 10 Gbps can also work over copper.

Comment: @DanielB True. I found that when I was looking for sample network cards. The advantage of SFP is it can use either one, and the advantage of fiber is distance. Admittedly, distance doesn't matter for a home PC-Server setup.